# Time Series - Compare two series and check for the relation between them

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have the following time series data. Series1 and Series2 are to be compared and to check for any relation between the two series.

My requirements are.
1) How to check whether there is any relation between the series, such that one series is impacting the other after certain days? How can it be established ?

series1 shows similarity to series2 after 40-50 days. but I got a correlation -0.3345712

```
   serdata <- read.csv("Timeseries.csv")
   library("graphics")
   plot.ts(serdata)
   cor(serdata$Series1,serdata$Series2)
```

2) What method can be used to analyse such data ? 
   Moving average can be applied or ARIMA to smooth the curve and to check for a fit ? (I am new to time series analysis. Please suggest any other method)

The data is

```
date    Series1 Series2
9/27/2016   5431    4451
9/28/2016   5468    4889
9/29/2016   5160    5002
9/30/2016   5267    5452
10/1/2016   5097    6223
10/2/2016   4749    6593
10/3/2016   5396    4574
10/4/2016   6001    4285
10/5/2016   6266    5323
10/6/2016   6344    4689
10/7/2016   5992    5499
10/8/2016   5147    5852
10/9/2016   4712    4987
10/10/2016  5328    2680
10/11/2016  6171    3128
10/12/2016  6235    2189
10/13/2016  7286    2532
10/14/2016  7230    3296
10/15/2016  7027    5019
10/16/2016  6063    4222
10/17/2016  5579    2482
10/18/2016  7155    2742
10/19/2016  6938    2611
10/20/2016  6805    2248
10/21/2016  6643    3463
10/22/2016  5620    5030
10/23/2016  6260    6164
10/24/2016  5504    4192
10/25/2016  4035    2879
10/26/2016  4054    2333
10/27/2016  6922    2710
10/28/2016  6848    3568
10/29/2016  5598    5415
10/30/2016  5069    5974
10/31/2016  5537    2314
11/1/2016   6264    2334
11/2/2016   7109    3379
11/3/2016   7411    2846
11/4/2016   7314    3183
11/5/2016   6095    4865
11/6/2016   5279    4948
11/7/2016   4295    3159
11/8/2016   4638    2724
11/9/2016   3536    2866
11/10/2016  3600    3600
11/11/2016  2995    5198
11/12/2016  2432    5192
11/13/2016  2516    4482
11/14/2016  2576    0
11/15/2016  3739    3
11/16/2016  3860    3284
11/17/2016  3587    2938
11/18/2016  3155    3710
11/19/2016  3446    4293
11/20/2016  2682    4239
11/21/2016  3198    4086
11/22/2016  3299    3054
11/23/2016  3134    3194
11/24/2016  2819    3033
11/25/2016  2324    3927
11/26/2016  2093    4824
11/27/2016  2493    4685
11/28/2016  3155    3072
11/29/2016  3510    3139
11/30/2016  3517    4363
12/1/2016   3315    2780
12/2/2016   3640    4075
12/3/2016   3186    5207
12/4/2016   2445    5327
12/5/2016   2812    4223
12/6/2016   3321    3179
12/7/2016   3163    3329
12/8/2016   3325    3747
12/9/2016   3007    3534
12/10/2016  2492    4673
12/11/2016  2364    5205
12/12/2016  2986    3600
12/13/2016  3313    4541
12/14/2016  3425    3823
12/15/2016  4385    3770
12/16/2016  3736    4370
12/17/2016  2336    4478
12/18/2016  2211    5396
12/19/2016  2322    5140
12/20/2016  2342    4089
12/21/2016  2262    4231
12/22/2016  2043    5657
12/23/2016  1723    6215
12/24/2016  1408    4211
12/25/2016  1463    0
12/26/2016  2248    5503
12/27/2016  3424    9483
12/28/2016  2925    6956
12/29/2016  2029    8992
12/30/2016  1950    6062
12/31/2016  1838    6326
1/1/2017    1964    7463
1/2/2017    2232    8426
1/3/2017    2480    8084
1/4/2017    2606    7026
1/5/2017    2606    6295
1/6/2017    2693    7179
1/7/2017    2458    5745
1/8/2017    2362    5690
1/9/2017    2767    5761
1/10/2017   2141    6332
1/11/2017   2355    6240
1/12/2017   3000    6710
1/13/2017   2921    5698
1/14/2017   2558    6156
1/15/2017   2407    7415
1/16/2017   2613    5742
1/17/2017   3005    5779
1/18/2017   3128    5784
1/19/2017   2961    5331
1/20/2017   2582    5476
1/21/2017   2191    7710
1/22/2017   2214    7187
1/23/2017   2649    7676
1/24/2017   3065    4742
1/25/2017   3216    5153
1/26/2017   3548    4817
1/27/2017   4316    5976
1/28/2017   4355    6145
1/29/2017   4848    5764
1/30/2017   4376    5305
1/31/2017   3808    4760
2/1/2017    4172    4752
2/2/2017    8098    4527
2/3/2017    7891    5206
2/4/2017    3484    6209
2/5/2017    3625    5729
2/6/2017    4219    7056
2/7/2017    4282    4955
2/8/2017    3982    4185
2/9/2017    3680    4090
2/10/2017   3314    3881
2/11/2017   2985    5280
2/12/2017   3266    6471
2/13/2017   3665    5840
2/14/2017   3892    4530
2/15/2017   3953    3993
2/16/2017   3855    4453
2/17/2017   3511    5570
2/18/2017   3222    7479
2/19/2017   3284    5349
2/20/2017   3615    4098
2/21/2017   3915    5032
2/22/2017   3994    4256
2/23/2017   3765    6215
2/24/2017   3494    4480
2/25/2017   3257    5995
2/26/2017   3399    6412
2/27/2017   3797    5450
2/28/2017   4076    3935
```

Comment: better to ask this in stack exchange file.  Look a [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133155/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-correctly-with-time-series) for example.

Comment: @agstudy Sure, Thanks.